# Jquery Datatable source from Application state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, datatables, redux

I have an application built using Reactjs -Redux. Now- Im trying to incorporate Jquery Datatable. So the data that I want to be on my datatable is fetched by dispatching action on my redux. Basically, I already have my data on my application state. I need this data from my application state to be on my jquery datatable. Like so:

```
    $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": application_state.data,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name[, ]" },
        { "data": "hr.0" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "extn" },
        { "data": "hr.2" },
        { "data": "hr.1" }
    ]
} );
```

Obviously, the above code won't work because like I said my data is already on my application state and I don't have to use "ajax". I also tried something like this:

```
    $('#example').DataTable( {
    "data": application_state.data,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name[, ]" },
        { "data": "hr.0" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "extn" },
        { "data": "hr.2" },
        { "data": "hr.1" }
    ]
} );
```

But, I still have no luck.

The JSON data that I have on my state is completely valid, it's an array of object. I just want it loaded on my jquery datatable. Now, there is one option that I know will work 100% but it's the dirty way. That is by building your data manually on the table. I meant creating the rows (`<tr><td>`..) by yourself. I don't like that.

Your response is greatly appreciated.
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it using `aoColumns` and `fnAddData`. Something like this:

```
// this is where field mapping happens
      const cols=[
         {'mDataProp':'<column/fieldname>'}
      ]
      const dataTableOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        bDestroy:true,
        pageLength: 25,
        deferRender:true,
        aoColumns:cols //The aoColumns
      }

      const _dt=$('#example')
              .dataTable(dataTableOptions);

    _dt.fnClearTable();
    _dt.fnAddData(<your state data here>)// Then Add your data using fnAddData
```

Thanks for viewing guys... cheers! I hope others will find this helpful too.